# How to Groupby(count) on one column in c++

Tags: c++, file, csv

I have a CSV file That have 2 columns, in every row, first item is a person ID and another item is his friend ID.
I want to groupby person IDs by their friends count in c++ and then sort that by friend count descending; How can i do that ?

my CSV file is like this:

```
ID,Friend_ID
P0,P1
P0,P2
P0,P3
P1,P0
P1,P2
P1,P3
P2,P0
P3,P0
P3,P1
```

and i want this :

```
ID,Frind_count
P0,3
P1,3
P3,2
P2,1
```

Comment: Its fairly straight forward. How did you attempt solving this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does it must be a c++ solution, or is it ok also a C commandline utility?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cluster the main problem into sub problems. From your given requirements the following steps are necessary:

1. Open input file
2. Read the file header of the CSV file
3. Read the complete data from the file and parse the single lines
4. Count, how many friends each person has
5. Sort the result based on the count in descending order
6. Write result to output file

All this can be done in ~25 lines of code. Function Main is consisting of ~12 lines. Please see below one possible solution. This solution makes usage of the std library.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

// Make reading easier
using PairOfFriends = std::pair<const std::string, std::string>; // This is exactly one pair of friends. With a const member for multimap "type_value"
using MmFriend = std::multimap<std::string, std::string>; // And this are all pairs of frineds in a sorted multimap

struct PairLine     // ! This is a proxy for the input_iterator !
{   // Input function. Read on line of text file and split it into 2 parts
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, PairLine& line)
    {   // We will use a regex iterator to be a little more tolerant for different separator characters
        std::string wholeLine;  std::regex comma("[ \t\n]*[,;.][ \t\n]*");
        std::getline(is, wholeLine);    // Read one complete line and split it into 2 parts
        std::vector<std::string> part{ std::sregex_token_iterator(wholeLine.begin(), wholeLine.end(), comma, -1), std::sregex_token_iterator() };
        if (2 == part.size()) line.pairString = std::make_pair(part[0], part[1]); // Copy the 2 parts in our internal variable
        return is; 
    }
    operator PairOfFriends() const { return pairString; } // Cast pairString to PairOfFriends. For input iterator.
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> pairString{};  // Internal representation. Attention! No const member!
};
struct PersonCount
{   // We will use this POD to store person names and related counts
    std::string person; unsigned int personCount;  // And we need also an output function
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const PersonCount& pc) { return (os << pc.person << "," << pc.personCount); }
};

int main()
{
    // 1. Open file. Will be closed by destructor ------------------------------
    std::ifstream inFileStream{ "r:\\person.csv" };             
    // 2. Read header ----------------------------------------------------------
    std::string header; std::getline(inFileStream, header);     
    // 3. Read the complete CSV file and put result into multimap --------------
    MmFriend mmFriend{ std::istream_iterator<PairLine>(inFileStream), std::istream_iterator<PairLine>() };
    // 4. Count how many friends persons have ----------------------------------
    std::vector<PersonCount> friendCount{}; // Person and Count will be stored here
    for (MmFriend::iterator it = mmFriend.begin(), end = mmFriend.end(); it != end; it = mmFriend.upper_bound(it->first)) { 
        friendCount.emplace_back(PersonCount{it->first, mmFriend.count(it->first) });  // Put count info into new arry
    }
    //5. Sort ------------------------------------------------------------------
    std::sort(friendCount.begin(), friendCount.end(), [](const PersonCount & p1, const PersonCount & p2) { return p2.personCount < p1.personCount; });
    // 6. Output ---------------------------------------------------------------
    std::ofstream outFileStream{"r:\\out.txt"};
    outFileStream << "ID,Friend_count\n";
    std::copy(friendCount.begin(), friendCount.end(), std::ostream_iterator<PersonCount>(outFileStream, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: For reading CSV data and parsing that, we use an input iterator. The whole parsing is done in main in 1 line. The Extractor functions parses an input line by using sregex_token_iterator. If this should be expanded to more than 2 entries, tuples can be used instead of standard pairs.

The rest is really easy. I guess, it does not need more explanation.

However. If necessary, I will of course answer questions.

Hope this helps